# sumar todos los numeros de un fichero txt python con sum()

Tags: python, archivo

Hola les adjunto el codigo que he hecho, el problema es que me da un error del tipo (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values')

```
f=open("datos.txt")
datos= f.readlines()
print(sum(datos))
f.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `datos` es una lista de strings. Cada string es una línea del archivo. No puedes sumar strings; tienes que convertirlos a entero primero: `sum(int(val) for val in datos)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un str no se puede sumar, seria como decir a+a y esto lo concatenaria, pero por la que sum no concatenaria por que es para números. Una buena solución, que no la única seria esto:

```
f=open("datos.txt")
#lista de str 
datos= f.readlines()
#No te aconsejo imprimir mucho de golpe porque print es una funcion muy lenta
print(sum(datos))
f.close()
#nueva lista
listint=[]

for i in datos:
    # se añaden los numeros convertidos en ints
    listint.append(int(i))

suma=sum(listint)
```

Comment: Solo para aclarar, print es lenta sin importar si imprimes mucho de golpe o si mandas una linea por milisegundo a la pantalla. En lo posible hay que evitar el uso de print para programas finales. Solo usarlo para pruebas.